# How to update MapView when Firebase sends location data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build a Tracking App. I made a login/register for every user. Upon logging in the user starts updating location data and sending it to Firebase, a TableView also gets populated with all users that registered. Upon clicking on a user in the TableView i present a new controller with a MapView. The problem is that i have no idea how to trigger getting Firebase location data without clicking on a button or similar, and the data shouldn't stop coming until exiting the MapView controller because the idea is to display the location of the user in realtime.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. You should read this to know how to post a proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can call location did update method in appdelegete class.

**For Swift**

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last{
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**For Objective C**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{  
    if(!newLocation) return;

    if ((oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude) &&(oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude))
    {        
      // to  draw path as new location find
        jogPoint = [[JogPoint alloc] initWithCenterCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];

        [jogPoints addObject:jogPoint];

     }
 }
```

Comment: Isnt that method returning the location of the device ? I need to update the MapView with location data which i get from Firebase (latitude and longitude)

Comment: This isn't what the OP was asking. He's asking how to continually get location data from the other users of the app - see his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way. I just needed to use Firebases build in observers and set them up.